# Validation on fields results by a SELECT query

Tags: apex, soql, json, validation, jsongenerator

I need to make a validation of the results query of many fields. 
Today this validation is being made one by one, in such effort that, in my opinion, could be less if we used a function and a list or even an array of this SELECT query results.

But I have two issues:

1. I do not know if the SELECT query result already is a list
2. I think that maybe the JSON generator already makes this validation of the null fields.

Actually, I only need the fields which are null be written "null" when the JSON is created. And the API works like is expected by the other system that consumes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want fields which you have queried but which have a null value to be included in a serialization of that record, you need to pass the second `suppressApexObjectNulls Boolean` parameter as `false`.

```
Account record = [SELECT SomeField__c FROM Account WHERE SomeField__c = null LIMIT 1];
String payload = JSON.serialize(record, /*suppressApexObjectNulls*/ false);
```

Comment: I did set the suppressApexObjectNulls Boolean parameter as false. But the API is giving me a blank result.
The validation is like:
`if (resultQuery == null || String.isEmpty(resultQuery)) { genaratorJson.writeNullFields(resultQuery) } else { set the value of the field on the variable}`

Comment: It is very hard to give proper help when your question contains none of your code.

Comment: Sorry, but it is gonna be awful if I put the entire code in here. Because it is not mine and the code has a lot of validation only with `if else`, making him being really big :/